# Azure DevOps/Pipelines seed job equivalent?

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I'm looking at moving to Azure and using Azure Pipelines (I've used Jenkins before now) - I plan to deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service and store my Docker images in an Azure Container Registry.  Using Azure DevOps/Pipelines to integrate with Azure's own services would seem to be simplest approach.

I've got a small collection of applications to deploy - about 30 or so.  In the Jenkins world I had a Git repository containing my job definitions written in Jenkins Job DSL language and a seed job that would create all 30 Jenkins "pipelines" for me.

Can I do this with Azure DevOps?  Is there an equivalent to a seed job process in Azure DevOps?

--

[Jenkinsfile equivalent in Azure repos](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/jenkinsfile-equivalent-in-azure-repos) looks to be a similar question (but not identical).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done, [Azure Pipelines](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/) can ingest a yaml file, configuring the pipeline as code. These yaml files should be source controlled and the pipeline can be set up to build in an automated way.

You can also [reuse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) steps within the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for this as well.

Templating is solved very good, and in case you have a file "azure-pipelines.yml" in the root of your repo, the pipeline will automatically be setup (with the name of the repo).

But if you have a repo with submodules (as in directories, not git submodules) and dedicated azure-pipeline.yml in each submodule, these will not be setup automatically. Maybe also because we are not enabled to define a pipeline name in our yaml definitions?

With a short testing round, I found that using the azure pipeline cli together with python is also no quick fix for really automatically setting up my pipelines for submodules.